# Attach a EBS volume with boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ebs

I was trying to add several EBS to an EC2 instance, I use something like that:

```
  block_map = BlockDeviceMapping()
  xvdf = EBSBlockDeviceType()
  xvdf.delete_on_termination = True
  xvdf.size = opts.ebs_vol_size
  block_map['/dev/xvdf'] = xvdf
  req = conn.request_spot_instances(key_name=opts.key_pair,
                                  price=opts.price,
                                  image_id=ami,
                                  security_groups=[instance_group],
                                  instance_type=opts.instance_type,
                                  block_device_map=block_map,
                                  count=count
                                  )
```

EBS are created as I could see them within the EC2 instance in the AWS console. Beside that, I'm 100% sure they are created as I can list them with the lsblk command once I log into the EC2 instance. I also added a couple of entries to my /etc/fstab so that the EBS volumes at mounted at creation time.

However, they are not mounted. If I run the command `mount -a` the following error shows up:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

So, it seems EBS volumes are created but not formatted with EBSBlockDeviceType. After I formatted, I can run `mount -a` again and they are already mounted.

My question is, if is possible to create and format a volume within the EBSBlockDeviceType() constructor, so that I can mount it.

Another option I think I might have is attach an already formatted EBS snapshot usign the snapshot_id field in the boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceType class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` command fails for a newly allocated volume because there is no file system on it. BlockDeviceType (or EBSBlockDeviceType) does not have an option to chose a file system for the  underlying EBS volume. Once the volume is allocated, user can create a file system of choice.

However, for a volume created from a formatted EBS snapshot (created from a volume having file system), there is no need to create file system again. You can use `file -s <device name>` to find out if the device already has a file system.

More details at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: Hi Mayank,

I suppossed that but I hoped that AWS cli would have some option to indicate the file system underneath. What I finally did was create a previous snapshot from a EBS volume and indicate its id as a call to EBSBlockDeviceType was made.